# How to force null in date field - access 2007?

Tags: c#, ms-access-2007

I have a table that contains date field.

How can I force `null` or `empty` value on this field?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "force"? Should it not be able to put any other value than null in the field? (A date field can't be empty.)

Comment: Set the Required property to No?

Comment: Please be specific in your question?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it by this:

```
string DOB = "null" // this solved it , null should be a text and not a value
if(tb_date !="")
 { DOB = "#"+tb_date.text+"#" ;}
```

//and in the query:
    `insert into table(....,DateofBirth,...) values (.... "',"+DOB+",'"+...) ;`

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to C# code, you can make the type nullable:

```
DateTime? dt = null;
```

Then acces it by:

```
if(dt == null)
  dosomething;
else
  myDT = dt.Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with ADO and a query, amongst other things:

```
 UPDATE jobs SET atable.adate = Null 
 WHERE atable.ID=342
```

Comment: This will work only if the Required property is set to NO and there's no unique index on the field that disallows Nulls.

Comment: That is true of any field, not just dates. As far as I know, Required defaults to No in Access and a unique index must be added.

Answer (score 0):

Just set `DBValue.Null` whatever field you want to set `Null`.